# Angular Bootstrap not going full responsive

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I've got a problem with [ngBootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/) in the sense that it's not making my app fully responsive, and I'm not completely sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if there is some error in the library.

Okay, so here's a screenshot of the part of my app that is not behaving correctly:

1. Full screen size, works good:

[image]

2. When making the window a little smaller, it keeps working good too, until this size:

[image]

3. But if the window gets smaller than that point, those three cards just stop resizing. You can see that the component below resizes better, though it also loses its right margin:

[image]

My parent template looks like this:

```
    <div class="margin content-margin" *ngIf="config"  >
  <div class="row">
    <p class="title">{{ title?.toUpperCase() }}</p>
    <ng-template #tipContent>
      <div class="tooltip-inner ">{{description}}</div>
    </ng-template>
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle bootstrap-tooltip tooltip-text tooltip-relocate selected-color" placement="right" [ngbTooltip]="tipContent"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="breadc">
        <breadcrumb [locations]="getBreadcrumb()"></breadcrumb>
      </div>
      <div class="filters-reset" (click)="resetFilters()">
        <i class="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Reset filters
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-separator">
      <card [title]="'DIMENSIONS'"  class="col col-sm-4" [enabled]="usesSegments ? 'true' : false" (cardOpen)="config?.cardStatus['segments'] = $event">
        <div class="margin">
          <segments [config]="config" [segmentsEnabled]="usesSegments" [cardOpen]="config?.cardStatus['segments']"></segments>
        </div>
    </card>
    <card [title]="'CHANNEL'"  class="col col-sm-4" (cardOpen)="config?.cardStatus['levelselect'] = $event">
      <levels-selector class="levels-wrapper" [config]="config" [cardOpen]="config?.cardStatus['levelselect']"></levels-selector>
    </card>
    <card [title]="'PERIOD'" class="col col-sm-4" (cardOpen)="config?.cardStatus['period_picker'] = $event">
      <period-picker-component class="period-picker"
        [cardOpen]="config?.cardStatus['period_picker']"
        [config]="config"
      >
      </period-picker-component>
    </card>
  </div>
    <div class="row row-separator" >
      <chart-card [title]="'CONVERSIONS GRAPH'" class="col" [config]="config" (cardOpen)="config?.cardStatus['chart'] = $event">
        <simple-chart-wrapper
            [chartOptions]="chartOptions"
            [config]="config"
            [cardOpen]="config?.cardStatus['chart']">
        </simple-chart-wrapper>
      </chart-card>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-separator">
        <table-card [title]="config?.data?.metric?.label + ' - '+ (config?.data?.filters?.period?.range)"
                    [downloadable]="true"
                    [tableController]="table"
                    class="col">
            <basic-table [config]="config" [table]="table"></basic-table>
        </table-card>
      </div>
</div>
```

Some of the class names you see applied to some of these tags are actually not being used. In case you want to see the CSS classes that are being applied, here you have a dump of the CSS that applies here:

```
.container{
    background-color: #dee3ea !important;
    min-width: 1px;
    min-height: 1px;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.title{
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.row-separator{
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.filters-reset{
    color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip-text{
    font-size: 20px !important;
}

.breadc{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px !important;
}


.content-margin{
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
```

I tried many things, like using more specific classes (like the col-sm ones), but nothing seems to work. These cards just won't resize past that point.

Do someone recognize what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Dependencies versions:

> "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6"
>
> "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2"

Comment: Include all your rows `<div class="row"></div>` inside a container class `<div class="container"></div>` and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @GirishaC No, it doesn't seem to be fixing anything, the behavior of the cards keeps being the same.

Comment: can u share a working snippet here or in codepen or ..., so that we can have a look at the issue u are facing, it's really hard to assume what might be the issue.